# RSA message encryption question

Tags: encryption, rsa

I'm very new to cryptography, I wanted to know what exactly do I have to do to encrypt a three-letter message using RSA? for example if I wanted to encrypt this message $M= \text{HCP}, p=11 q=13$.

Do I have to change the letters into numbers? ($H = 7, C=2, P=15$) and then encrypt each letter alone? or add/multiply them and encrypt them all at once?

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$ in this context? Are you talking about RSA, for example? If so, you should make that clearer in your question

Comment: Yes, im sorry i forgot to say i'm talking about RSA algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encrypt a message, in RSA or other encryption schemes, we convert (encode) the messages into bits/bytes arrays that are dependent on the scheme in an invertible way!

If you consider only the English letters, with $A=0,\ldots, Z=25$ then you can make the encoding of a sequence of letters $m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_t$ with

$$m = \sum_{i=0}^t 26^i \cdot m_i$$ This method is common way to encode, remember the binary encoding? A similar idea applied here, and note that the decoding is unique. Numbers are easily converted into octets (bytes) in a computer and usually byte array is processed, some schemes use words, too.

You are going to have some problems now or future;

1. You cannot have $m \geq n$ where $n$ is the RSA modulus. If your messages are longer than the RSA modulus, then you need to split your message into parts.

   In your case, $p=11,q=13$ then $n = 143$. This can only encrypt one letter at a time. Use larger modulus, or encrypt one by one!.
2. We don't use RSA for encryption, we rather use it for signatures and for hybrid encryption like RSA-KEM.
3. RSA encryption needs proper padding like PKCS#1v.4 or OAEP to be secure against the attack, see [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/RSA-survey.pdf).
4. [RSA Signing is Not RSA Decryption](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php)
5. For signature, one must use the Probabilistic Signature Scheme (PSS).
6. The padding, is not enough to be secure, one needs to have constant time implementation against the side-channel attacks.
7. To see how real RSA encodes see [rfc8017](https://tools.ietf.org/html/)

Comment: That's an advanced yet understandable answer, thank you so much, and speaking of RSA signing, is it a type of verification process? or is it somehow authentication?

Comment: Yes, signing is an authentication and [more than that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87723/18298)